# Adjust image brightness and contrast using the average of the luma channel

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, yuv, brightness

I want to adjust the brightness and contrast of an image using this pixel transformation operation:

*g(i, j) = α * f(i, j) + β*

where *f(i, j)* is the original BGR image, *g(i, j)* is the adjusted image, and *(i, j)* are the pixel indices.

The alpha and beta parameters (aka gain and bias) can apparently be estimated using the average of the luma channel (Y') from the Y'UV color space (aka YUV).[1]

First, I find the average of the luma channel:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

bgr = cv2.imread('/original_image.png')

bgr_avgs = np.average(np.average(bgr, axis=0), axis=0) # find avg of each channel
y_coeffs = np.array([ 0.114, 0.587, 0.299 ]) # BGR
luma_avg = np.dot(y_coeffs, bgr_avgs)
```

I then want to calculate alpha and beta from luma_avg to do the following transformation:

```
adjusted_img = cv2.convertScaleAbs(bgr, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)
```

I am open to using another method. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

[1] El Harraj and Raissouni claimed alpha (gain) and beta (bias) could be estimated from the average luma in the last paragraph of page 7 in their paper [OCR Accuracy Improvement on Dcoument Images Through a Novel Pre-Processing Approach, SIPIJ Vol.6, No.4 (Aug 2015)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1509/1509.03456.pdf#page=7).

Comment: There are 2 unknown. You said *"... can supposedly be estimated"* but how can be estimated, where did you read it?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I added a link above to my reference.